# Failed to read FDPMA queued

Tags: grub2, hard-drive, lenovo

Dual boot Ubuntu 14.04 and Win7

Fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04 on Lenovo G510.

Every thing appears fine until reboot, then I get Failed to read FDPMA queued. After a few reboots I might get back in.

reboot 
Then comes Attempt to read outside 'hd0'
reboot 
Followed by error: unknown filesystem
grub rescue>
Now no number of reboots will get me back in.

I would have just given up on the HDD at this point, but after 3 installs of Ubuntu I'm still able to boot the Windows OS.

Any ideas how I can get Ubuntu booting regularly?

Some suggest the Failed to read FDPMA Queued error is a cable problem, but that's not easy to replace in a laptop and I can't find anything to connect all 3 errors.

This doesn't work for me:
http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem was related to Suspending. Somehow it was breaking Grub. Repairing Grub didn't work with the first install, did work with a broken fresh install.

So this did work: http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd

I have then edited the logind.conf with these instructions to ignore the laptop lid:

> To get started:
>
> 1. Press Ctrl+Alt+T on keyboard to open the terminal. When it opens, run the >command below to open the configuration file via gedit editor:
>
>    sudo gedit /etc/systemd/logind.conf
>
> Replace gedit with vi or other text editor if you’re on Server edition.
>
> 2. Find out the line #HandleLidSwitch=suspend, remove the # and change it to:
>
>    HandleLidSwitch=poweroff to shutdown computer when lid is closed
>    HandleLidSwitch=hibernate to hibernate computer when lid is closed
>    HandleLidSwitch=ignore to do nothing
> 3. Save the file and restart the service or just restart your laptop to apply >changes.
>
>    sudo restart systemd-logind

which I found here:
http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/04/shutdown-ubuntu-14-04-lts-when-the-lid-is-closed/

I think the problem is something to do with the Hybrid Video Card and Suspending. I am happy to avoid Suspending.